# Reverse DNS propagation and caching

Tags: domain-name-system, reverse-dns, systemd-resolve

I set up a VPS (Ubuntu 22.04, at Contabo in Germany) yesterday. Unfortunately, I got the reverse DNS entry incorrect (I entered `example.org` instead of `example.uk`). I spotted this quickly, and corrected it, and both `mxtoolbox.com` and `dig` on my local system then showed it correctly resolving to `example.uk`.

This new system has to talk to a mail server, which is also Ubuntu 22.04 (at Ionos in the UK). However, `postfix` on the mail server rejects incoming mails, because the incoming IP address is still resolving to `example.org`. This has been carrying on for about 16 hours. There was a period last night when mails *were* being delivered, but they're not being delivered now.

On the mail server, `dig +noall +answer -x ip-addr` shows a 2-hour countdown in the TTL. However, it then just cycles again, but still shows `example.org`. If I flush the local cache with `sudo resolvectl flush-caches` it makes no difference, but starts the countdown again. I've tried this on another VPS in the same datacentre (Ionos, UK) and it shows the same results.

So, I'm guessing that Ionos has an rDNS cache that ignores the upstream TTL (since `mxtoolbox` and my own local `dig` have been showing the correct `example.uk` result for 16+ hours). Does that make sense? Can I set up the local resolver on the mail server to (temporarily) ignore any upstream caches and get an authoritative answer? How do you even get an authoritative answer on reverse DNS?

Comment: You are asking about (by nature) public DNS records. These types of questions are *much* easier to diagnose when you mention the specific record you care about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not much you can do, other than triple checking everything is correct now, and waiting. One way to check if the records look good at your providers servers would be to ask `dig` to iteratively query all the way from the root:

```
dig -x 2a02:c205:f00::1:2:3 +trace
```

`ns1.contabo.net` gives me 24 hour TTL. Though some caching resolvers might disregard that, that is how long your old records might still be visible to anyone recently interacting with you.

Comment: `+trace` looks nice - working through it. Fair point on the on the public records - it's 217.76.55.194.

Comment: So... `+trace` gives the correct answer. Working through the trace (with some help from https://superuser.com/a/715656/1681094) I can see that Contabo has 3 name servers, all authoritative (`aa` flag) for this query, and all giving the correct result. However, as far as I can see, `trace` doesn't tell you anything about the route taken by a plain `dig` query, so I can't see where in the path an incorrect cached entry is being used. So, yes, just wait... :/